# Want to modify Hibernate criteria using entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-criteria

In my example I created a Hibernate criteria only using my entity object "contract".

```
     @Transactional
    public static List<Contract> findAllContractsPerContract(Contract contract) {
        EntityManager e = entityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        Session session = e.unwrap(Session.class);
        Example contractExample = Example.create(contract).excludeProperty("fromDate").excludeProperty("endDate");;
        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Contract.class).add(contractExample);
        // here some restriction can be done. (in a dynamic way like equlas/greater/less...)
        List<Contract> list = c.list();
        return list;
    }
```

The contract object has many parameters. In this case all the parameters of contract are searched by equals. So, if the parameters are matching, I get the right results.

But now I want do add some criteria to some parameters of contract object. Two parameter for example are: "**fromDate**" and "**endDate**". Its possible to modify the existing criteria like **>= fromDate and <=endDate** (or between). The criteria should also be dynamically.

I Know that I can add some criteria at the end of this line:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Contract.class).add(contractExample);
```

But this is only a addition to the existing query. 
Is there a solution or another technical way to solve the problem?

Thanks for input.

**Update 1**

Request without Operands:

```
allRequestParams={"v00Datvon":"09-07-2014","v00Datbis":"09-07-2014","v00Saicode":{"saiCode":"SO02"}}
```

Request with Operands example

```
allRequestParams={"v00Datvon":"09-07-2014","operand":"less","v00Datbis":"09-07-2014","operand":"greater","v00Saicode":{"saiCode":"SO02","operand":"equals"}}
```

In Controller I get the JSON String like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=text/plain")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getVertagFromSearch(@RequestParam String allRequestParams, ModelMap model) throws JsonProcessingException{
//do stuff
}
```

**Update 2**

One other big problem is the subdomainobject of contract. v00Saicode depends on contract.
Same problem with the dates. Without parsing the JSON String to contract object, I lose the transformation of Calender class.
I really stock how I should react in the controller. Has anybody a solution.

**Solution**

This is my way to do all the parts in a dynamic way.

The request got an additional part for the operators.

The Controller received the String like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=text/plain")
public ResponseEntity<String> getVertagFromSearch(@RequestParam String allRequestParams,@RequestParam String operators, ModelMap model) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, IntrospectionException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    HashMap<String, String> operatorsMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(operators, HashMap.class);
    Contract contract = Contract.fromJsonToContract(allRequestParams);
    List<Contract> list = Contract.findAllContractsPerContract(contract, operatorsMap);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(Contract.toJsonArray(list),headers,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The DAO and the call to a helper class

```
      public static List<Contract> findAllContractsPerContract(Contract contract, Map<String, String> operatorMap) throws IntrospectionException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    EntityManager e = entityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    Session session = e.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Contract.class);
    criteria = CriteriaBuilder.buildCriteria(contract, criteria, operatorMap);
    List<Contract> list = criteria.list();
    return list;
}
```

The Criteria Builder helper class and code of @Jeff answer:

```
public static Criteria buildCriteria(Object object, Criteria criteria, Map<String,String> operatorMap) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IntrospectionException{
     BeanInfo vertagInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Contract.class);
        for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : vertagInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()){
            String propertyString = propertyDescriptor.getName();
            Object value = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(object);
            if(propertyString.equals("class")||value==null){
                continue;
            }
            String operator = operatorMap.get(propertyString);
            if(operator==null){
                operator="EQ";
            }
            criteria.add(Comparison.valueOf(operator).convert(propertyString, value));
        }
    return criteria;
}
```

Comment: Any other help for this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your sticking point in the Controller layer.  What library are you using to parse JSON into Java objects?  You shouldn't have to settle for either a Contract object or a String of the data; you should be able to create a new DTO (ContractCriteria or something) that the JSON deserializes to and it can have internal Calendar members.

Comment: @Jeff The updated answer woked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the values for from date and end date from your `Contract` instance and then set them to null in that instance.  `Example.create(contract)` will not add the default eq restriction for those null fields, and you can then follow @Pracede's code to do the ge and le restrictions.

You could probably also call excludeProperty() on your `Example` instance for the date fields you are going to manually add.  That's probably the more elegant way to go.

**Update**

If you need this to build criteria dynamically based on input from the user, then query by example probably isn't the way to go.  Create an enum that can handle all the comparison types you care about and return the appropriate Criterion comparison for each type:

```
public enum Comparison {
    EQ {
        @Override
        public Criterion convert(String propertyName, Object propertyValue) {
            return Restrictions.eq(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    },
    LE {
        @Override
        public Criterion convert(String propertyName, Object propertyValue) {
            return Restrictions.le(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    },
    LIKE {
        @Override
        public Criterion convert(String propertyName, Object propertyValue) {
            return Restrictions.like(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    };

    public abstract Criterion convert(String propertyName, Object propertyValue);
}
```

Then when you're processing your JSON input in the controller, get the correct enum type for each comparison, and let it give you the restriction you need:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Contract.class);
for each name, value, comparator in JSON data*
    c.add(Comparison.valueOf(comparator).convert(name, value)
```

*Note: I'm not suggesting you move DAO code up into the controller; instead of passing a Contract instance to your DAO, pass an array of objects that represent the data from JSON input.

Comment: With the `excludeProperty()` method it works for me. Do you have a solution for a dynamic way to create Hibernate restrictions. Because I dont now, which restriction will come to the controller. (ge/le/eq) Thanks.

Comment: How is the controller indicating that something other than an equals comparison should happen?

Comment: It should come from the UI part. There should be an ajax call which sends the parameter in JSON format.

Comment: Updated answer to include dynamic restrictions

Comment: Thats a really good solution. Do you have any suggestions how I need to send the json request. And to use the String in Controller. Maybe a Map with one Key and two values? See Details at updated question

Comment: Do you have a solution for the controller part? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
 if(fromDate!= null && endDate=null) {
                criteria.add(Expression.ge("date", fromDate));

                criteria.add(Expression.le("date", endDate));
            }
```

You have to add the next criteria to the current one.

Comment: I tried already this: **c.add(Restrictions.ge("fromDate", contract.getFromDate()))** but then I get an empty list. Without adding the entity to the criteria, it worked.

Comment: Check if the database date format is the same as the one provide by Criteria.

Comment: yes its the same. I think I need to write another method to create the restrictions dynamically. (CriteriaBuilder) Or is there any other solution. If anybody need more input please let me know. Thanks